# MATLAB Overload plus operator

Tags: matlab, function, operator-overloading, return-value

I want to create a function in MATLAB by using the plus operator (i.e. plus(a,b)) where when the user passes two strings, they are concatenated together and displayed as the result. However, every time I check on this, I get the error that I cannot implement built-in functions. Is it possible to do this in MATLAB and if it is possible, what is the procedure of doing it?

Any help on this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Create a directory called `@char`
2. Inside that directory place a function similar to the following:

   ```
   function c = plus(a,b)
   c = horzcat(a,b); %// if you want the result to be output
   disp(c) %// if you want the result to be displayed
   ```
3. Ensure that the parent directory of the `@char` directory is on the MATLAB path (or is the Current Directory).
4. Use the function

   ```
   >> 'abc' + 'def'
   abcdef
   ans =
   abcdef
   ```

Comment: I never knew about overloading exists in Matlab 0.o.

Comment: Thanks Phil Goddard, it was very helpful.